# Does rails use method: :patch for editing with _form.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, erb

I am following along with the Ruby on Rails tutorial guide for [getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/getting_started.html#updating-articles) and am in section [5.12 Using partials to clean up duplication in views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/getting_started.html#using-partials-to-clean-up-duplication-in-views). I understand [why partials are used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15471159/5225057) per the D.R.Y. convention, however, I am curious about a difference in the new.html.erb and edit.html.erb. Specifically, prior to using the partial _form.html.erb file, the edit.html.erb file explicitly called `method: :patch`

```
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
...
```

... and now the _form.html.erb file covers both new & edit without explicitly calling [PATCH](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/patch.html):

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
...
```

Is PATCH still being invoked "behind the scenes" for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the tutorial you shared:

> The reason we can use this shorter, simpler form_for declaration to stand in for either of the other forms is that @article is a resource corresponding to a full set of RESTful routes, and Rails is able to infer which URI and method to use.

Also, from the [reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style) given there:

For an existing `resource` or `record` for `@post`, it is equivalent to:

```
<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_post", id: "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Whereas, for a new record of the resource, i.e. `Post.new`, it is equivalent to

```
<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: posts_path, html: { class: "new_post", id: "new_post" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Thus, in this case, magic lies in the rails with 2 things, helping rails understand what to do with this form:

1. Your defined routes for your model, `resources :article`
2. The type(Existing record or a new record) of `resource` object passed to `form_for`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `form_for` checks whether the model is persisted to know whether it needs to perform a `POST` (create) or `PATCH` (update).