# How does form_for knows what URL/path to go when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a scaffold named User. I checked the code of the partial view "_form" and I see the code snippet below:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f|  %>
   <div class=field>
      <%= f.label :firstname %>
      <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

So if you click the submit button generated by the code above, how does rails know what URL/path to go since it didn't specify there what path to look for?

Comment: Little _rails magic_, read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does rails use method: :patch for editing with \_form.html.erb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795769/does-rails-use-method-patch-for-editing-with-form-html-erb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from [Amr El Bakry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827499/1977104), let me help you demystifying the Rails magic behind the `form_for` helper method.

So your question is basically: how does `form_for` find out the route to submit to and how does it distinguish between creating/updating the record?

Rails actually sorts this out through **[record identification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification)**. An example is worthy at this point:

```ruby
## Creating a new user
# long style
form_for(@user, url: users_path)
# short style - record identification gets used
form_for(@user)

## Updating an existing user
# long style
form_for(@user, url: user_path(@user), html: { method: "patch" })
# short style - record identification to the rescue
form_for(@user)
```

You can clearly see that the **short style** is the *same* for both cases. 
Record identification is smart enough to figure out *if the record is new or an existing one* by invoking `@user.persisted?`.

You may be interested to assert this fact yourself in the `form_for` definition inside the **form_helper.rb** on [line 462](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/612572746c311b69d617a7f0d6eb6bdbad82780c/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L462) !

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

In your **config/routes.rb** file, you'll find Rails has added `resources :users` when you generated the scaffold. This is called a **resourceful route**, and it creates seven different routes for your `user` resource; each route maps an HTTP verb and a URL to a controller action.

In your case, when you submit the form, the HTTP verb is **POST**, the path is `/users` mapped to the `create` action inside the `users` controller. This is Rails default and you can read all about it in the [Rails Guides on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: ok so it looks for a pattern having the POST HTTP verb within the routes created by the resource route of the controller? So for example if I have two resourceful route:
resources :user
 and 
resources :post

if the form view is created from the user, then it will look only for the route having POST verb in resources :user routes?

Also what about the Edit? How does it know the form is intended for creating new record, or just editing a record?

Comment: it looks for the first match to the HTTP verb and the URL `/users` in the routes file. @Wasif Hossain elaborated more on this and on how it know when to edit.